# Mixing aggregation and group by in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

What I have is a data set called 'report' which has details of delivery drivers.  'Pass' means they delivered on time and 'Fail' means they didn't

```
Name|Outcome
A   |Pass
B   |Fail
C   |Pass
D   |Pass
A   |Fail
C   |Pass
```

What I want

```
Name|Pass|Fail|Total
A   |1   |1   |2
B   |0   |1   |1
C   |2   |0   |2
D   |1   |0   |1
```

I tried:

```
report.groupby(['Name','outcome']).agg(['count'])
```

but it is not giving me the required output

Many Thanks

Comment: Your output is wrong. Why does `B` have `1` at `Pass` and `0` at `Fail`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out..corrected

Answer (score 6):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with `margins=True` and `margins_name` parameter:

```
print (pd.crosstab(df['Name'], df['Outcome'], margins=True, margins_name='Total'))
Outcome  Fail  Pass  Total
Name                      
A           1     1      2
B           1     0      1
C           0     2      2
D           0     1      1
Total       2     4      6
```

And then remove last row with positions by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = pd.crosstab(df['Name'], df['Outcome'], margins=True, margins_name='Total').iloc[:-1]
print (df)
Outcome  Fail  Pass  Total
Name                      
A           1     1      2
B           1     0      1
C           0     2      2
D           0     1      1
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael . Great optimized version of crosstab

Comment: @NithinNampoothiry - yop, unfortunately it also add last `Total` column, so necessary remove it.

Answer (score 5):

This is `pd.crosstab` with `sum` over `axis=1`:

```
df = pd.crosstab(df['Name'], df['Outcome'])
df['Total'] = df[['Fail', 'Pass']].sum(axis=1)
```

```
Outcome  Fail  Pass  Total
Name                      
A           1     1      2
B           1     0      1
C           0     2      2
D           0     1      1
```

---

Or to remove the column axis name, we use `rename_axis`:

```
df = pd.crosstab(df['Name'], df['Outcome']).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis='columns')
df['Total'] = df[['Fail', 'Pass']].sum(axis=1)
```

```
  Name  Fail  Pass  Total
0    A     1     1      2
1    B     1     0      1
2    C     0     2      2
3    D     0     1      1
```

Comment: i normally use `margins=True` with `iloc[:-1]` chained to remove the row level shame you can't specify axis in the margin argument

Comment: @Datanovice - exactly, added answer.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what  I wanted. Never knew about the crosstab function in pandas. Thanks a lot @Erfan  !

Answer (score 1):

```py
In [1]: from io import StringIO

In [2]: df_string = '''Name|Outcome^M
   ...: A   |Pass^M
   ...: B   |Fail^M
   ...: C   |Pass^M
   ...: D   |Pass^M
   ...: A   |Fail^M
   ...: C   |Pass'''


In [3]: report = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df_string), sep='|')

In [4]: report.assign(count=1).groupby(["Name", "Outcome"])["count"].sum().unstack().assign(Total=lambda df: df.sum(axis=1))
Out[4]:
Outcome  Fail  Pass  Total
Name
A         1.0   1.0    2.0
B         1.0   NaN    1.0
C         NaN   2.0    2.0
D         NaN   1.0    1.0
```

Now you can fill NAs values using the `fillna(0)` method

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it using `pandas.dummies` and `groupby` :

```
report = pd.get_dummies(df1, columns=['outcome']).groupby(['name'], as_index=False).sum().rename(columns={"outcome_Fail":"Fail", "outcome_Pass":"Pass"})

report["Total"] = report["Pass"] + report["Fail"]

print(report)
```

Output:

```
    name Fail Pass Total
0   A     1    1    2
1   B     1    0    1
2   C     0    2    2
3   D     0    1    1
```